# how to properly save a dictionary inside a multiprosesing pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

im trying to parallelize a function in python, for this i need to encode some faces and then save the dict, i realize that when i try my code it only saved the last part of the data that its procesing, here is the code

```
train_dir = "/home/workstation/Desktop/fv/api/"
names = [l for l in os.listdir(train_dir)]
def functionist(name_list):
    X = []
    y = []
    verbose = True
    # Loop through each person in the training set
    for class_dir in name_list:

        # Loop through each training image for the current person
        for img_path in image_files_in_folder(os.path.join(train_dir, class_dir)):
            image = face_recognition.load_image_file(img_path)
            face_bounding_boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(image)

            if len(face_bounding_boxes) != 1:
                # If there are no people (or too many people) in a training image, skip the image.
                if verbose:
                    print("Image {} not suitable for training: {}".format(img_path, "Didn't find a face" if len(face_bounding_boxes) < 1 else "Found more than one face"), end="\r")
            else:
                # Add face encoding for current image to the training set
                X.append(face_recognition.face_encodings(image, known_face_locations=face_bounding_boxes)[0])
                y.append(class_dir)

    dictionary = dict(zip(y, X))
    with open('dataset_faces.dat', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(dictionary, f)
    return dictionary

cores = mp.cpu_count()
df_split = np.array_split(names, cores, axis=0)
pool = Pool(cores)
df_out = np.vstack(pool.map(functionist, df_split))
pool.close()
pool.join()
pool.clear()
```

i hope you can help me to figure out how can i make it save all the dictionary of face encodings? thanks so much for reading

Comment: you cannot access ressources of  process "A" from process "B" that is not possible! but you can use a database(sqlite) for this or a file or a pipe or a queue class from the multiprocessing library

Comment: df_out only contains the last part or the file 'dataset_faces.dat' only contains the last part?

Comment: i dont know if it is really the last part, i supose it cause the name start with V and it is the higher letter on the names jeje